# How to avoid mysterious behavior of Javascript objects?

Tags: javascript

In an earlier question, I was receiving multiple object keys upon query. Passing beyond that, I constructed a very small object example to discover how to work with objects. I am working with Firefox 51.0.1 on a macbook air 2 (yosemite) -uptodate The results I am getting are totally inexplicable. Can someone explain these results, and suggest how to fix this?

## Expected output

> object 0
>     j 0 key aprop obj(key) 1
>     j 1 key bprop obj(key) "one"
>     j 2 key cprop obj(key) [1]
>   0: (aprop): [1],(bprop): ["two"],(cprop): [[1]],
>     object 1
>     j 0 key aprop obj(key) 2
>     j 1 key bprop obj(key) "two"
>     j 2 key cprop obj(key) [2,2]
>   1: (aprop): [2],(bprop): ["two"],(cprop): [[2,2]],
>     object 2
>     j 0 key aprop obj(key) 3
>     j 1 key bprop obj(key) "three" 
>     j 2 key cprop obj(key) [3,3,3]
>   2: (aprop): 3,(bprop): ["three"],(cprop): [[3,3,3]],

## Actual Output

> object 0
>     j 0 key aprop obj(key) 1
>     j 1 key aprop obj(key) 1
>     j 2 key aprop obj(key) 1
>   0: (aprop): [1],(aprop): [1],(aprop): [1],
>     object 1
>     j 0 key bprop obj(key) two
>     j 1 key bprop obj(key) two
>     j 2 key bprop obj(key) two
>   1: (bprop): [two],(bprop): [two],(bprop): [two],
>     object 2
>     j 0 key cprop obj(key) 3,3,3
>     j 1 key cprop obj(key) 3,3,3
>     j 2 key cprop obj(key) 3,3,3
>   2: (cprop): [3,3,3],(cprop): [3,3,3],(cprop): [3,3,3],

```js
var objList = [];

class TestObj {
  constructor(aprop, bprop, cprop) {
    this.aprop = aprop;
    this.bprep = bprop;
    this.cprep = cprop;
    this.dprop = 0;
  }
  getAprop() {
    return aprop;
  }
  getBprop() {
    return bprop;
  }
  getCprop() {
    return cprop;
  }
  getDprop() {
    return dprop;
  }

  setAprop(arg) {
    aprop = arg;
  }
  setBprop(arg) {
    bprop = arg;
  }
  setCprop(arg) {
    cprop = arg;
  }
  setDprop(arg) {
    dprop = arg;
  }
}

var keylist = ["aprop", "bprop", "cprop"];

function create() {
  putList();
  var t1 = objList[1];
  alert("fromlist " + t1);

  for (var i = 0; i < objList.length; i++) {
    var s = "" + i + ": ";
    var obj = objList[i];
    console.log("   object " + i);
    for (var j = 0; j < keylist.length; j++) {
      var key = keylist[i];
      console.log("   j " + j + " key " + key + " obj(key) " + obj[key]);

      s += "(";
      s += key;
      s += ")";
      s += ": ";
      s += "[";
      s += obj[key];
      s += "]";
      s += ",";
    }
    console.log(s);
  }
}

function putList() {
  onlist(1, "one" [1]);
  onlist(2, "two", [2, 2]);
  onlist(3, "three", [3, 3, 3]);
}

function onlist(a, b, c) {
  var item = new TestObj();
  item["aprop"] = a;
  item["bprop"] = b;
  item["cprop"] = c;
  objList.push(item);
}

create();
```

Comment: Why are you creating objects using string concatenation?

Comment: `var key = keylist[i];` - shouldn't it be `keylist[j]`? I'd suggest using `forEach` or `_.each` (from underscore.js) to avoid such mistakes (if it is).

Comment: Should `getAprop() { return aprop; }` be `getAprop() { return this.aprop; }`? Same for your setters. Otherwise you're setting and getting global property values, not instance property values.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting expected output because of few typos:

1. `var key = keylist[j];` // need to use j instead of i pointed by yeputons in comment
2. `onlist(1, "one", [1]);` // a **,** (comma) was missing here

Fixed Snippet: (output is as expected)

```js
var objList = [];

class TestObj {
  constructor(aprop, bprop, cprop) {
    this.aprop = aprop;
    this.bprep = bprop;
    this.cprep = cprop;
    this.dprop = 0;
  }
  getAprop() {
    return aprop;
  }
  getBprop() {
    return bprop;
  }
  getCprop() {
    return cprop;
  }
  getDprop() {
    return dprop;
  }

  setAprop(arg) {
    aprop = arg;
  }
  setBprop(arg) {
    bprop = arg;
  }
  setCprop(arg) {
    cprop = arg;
  }
  setDprop(arg) {
    dprop = arg;
  }
}

var keylist = ["aprop", "bprop", "cprop"];

function create() {
  putList();
  var t1 = objList[1];

  for (var i = 0; i < objList.length; i++) {
    var s = "" + i + ": ";
    var obj = objList[i];
    console.log("   object " + i);
    for (var j = 0; j < keylist.length; j++) {
      var key = keylist[j];
      console.log("   j " + j + " key " + key + " obj(key) " + obj[key]);

      s += "(";
      s += key;
      s += ")";
      s += ": ";
      s += "[";
      s += obj[key];
      s += "]";
      s += ",";
    }
    console.log(s);
  }
}

function putList() {
  onlist(1, "one", [1]);
  onlist(2, "two", [2, 2]);
  onlist(3, "three", [3, 3, 3]);
}

function onlist(a, b, c) {
  var item = new TestObj();
  item["aprop"] = a;
  item["bprop"] = b;
  item["cprop"] = c;
  objList.push(item);
}

create();
```

Notes: setters/ getters are not being used, I have left them as suchin snippet for reference.